# How to disable list view item based on string value?

Tags: android, firebase, listview, android-listview

I am creating an application that pulls data from a firebase database and presents it to the user in a custom listview. I want to make it so that in a list item, if the textview contains the word "Unavailable", the user shouldn't be unable to select that list item. How can I achieve this dynamically ?

Java Code:

```
    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("TimeSlots").orderByChild("id");
        FirebaseListOptions<BookingTimes> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<BookingTimes>()
                .setLayout(R.layout.time_list_layout_adapter)
                .setLifecycleOwner(getActivity())
                .setQuery(query, BookingTimes.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(options)
        {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, Object model, int position)
            {
                timeTextV = v.findViewById(R.id.timeTV);
                availabilityTextv = v.findViewById(R.id.availabilityTV);

                BookingTimes bookingTimes = (BookingTimes) model;
                timeTextV.setText(bookingTimes.getTime());
                availabilityTextv.setText(bookingTimes.getAvailability());

                /*if (availabilityTextv.getText().toString().equals("Unavailable"))
                {
                    availabilityTextv.setEnabled(false);
                }*/ //<==== doesn't work
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
            {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled(int position)
            {
                /*if(position == 3)
                {
                    return false;
                } //<== this works, but how do i do it dynamically based on value?*/
                /*if(availabilityTextv.getText().toString().equals("Unavailable"))
                {
                    getItem(position);
                    return false;
                }*/ //<== doesn't work
                return super.isEnabled(position);
            }
        };

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Custom List View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/transparent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeTV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/availabilityTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

BookingTimes class:

```
public class BookingTimes
{
    private String time;
    private String availability;

    public BookingTimes()
    {

    }

    public BookingTimes(String Time, String Availability)
    {
        this.time = Time;
        this.availability = Availability;
    }

    public String getTime()
    {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String Time)
    {
        this.time = Time;
    }

    public String getAvailability()
    {
        return availability;
    }

    public void setAvailability(String Availability)
    {
        this.availability = Availability;
    }
}
```

Database:

[image]

Application:

[image]

Comment: do like this inside isEnabled-> adapter.getRef(position); to get the item and then fetch value and compare.

Comment: Please also add the content of your `BookingTimes` class.

Comment: The content of the BookingTimes class has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use the item availability directly in `isEnabled(int)`.

```
new FirebaseListAdapter<BookingTimes>(options)
{
    ...

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position)
    {
        return getItem(position).getAvailability().equals("Unavailable");
    }
}
```

Also keep in mind that `FirebaseListAdapter` has a generic parameter type. Also make sure to not views like `timeTextV` or `availabilityTextv`, preferably with the view holder pattern.